# Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Creating a Certificate authority signing request (Keychain Access, Certificate Assistant: "Request Certificate from Certificate Authority") generates a public/private key pair. If i export the public key (.pem format) and the private key (.p12 format) and import in snow leopard it import and work properly.
 but when i import in lion mac os it giving error:- unable to import an item UNIX per mission denied.and other dialog box The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.

i have giving permission to /Library/Keychains/login.keychain folder read\write.but not working.

please resolved it..

my question is if public/private key generated in lion cannot used by lion mac os...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the file system permissions of the .p12 file are incorrect. Try using the finder or the terminal to make sure that the owner is set to the user you are logged in as and that the owner has read/write permission for the file.

Xcode 4 has an option in the organizer to export everything needed to transfer your developer credentials to another machine.

From Apple's documentation:

1. In the devices organizer, select your team in the Teams section.
2. Click Export.
3. Specify a filename and a password, and click Save.

Comment: transfer of key from lion to snow leopard wroked.but lion to lion not wroking and alos with snow to lion not working. and i hve give permission to the keychain folder but still not worked

Comment: Also a helpful link http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.de/2011/07/saving-your-private-key-and.html

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do exactly. keys are not requered to transfer. just use the certificate that you have generated or p12